# Spring boot variable/nested request body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

I am working on a Spring Boot application that allows users to upload logic expression to the server. A web app allows them to visually create the expression. The result of the web app looks something like this

```
{
  "id": "someId",
  "fullexpression": {
    "left": "a",
    "operator": "AND",
    "right": {
        "left": {
            "left": "x",
            "operator": "AND",
            "right": "y",
        }
        "operator": "OR",
        "right": "z"
    }
  }
}
```

The above example describes the expression **a AND ((x AND y) OR z)**.

I've found a [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body) that says:

> the type we annotate with the @RequestBody annotation must correspond to the JSON sent from our client-side controller

If I understood the article correctly, it's not possible to do this directly. What is the best way to build a Spring Boot rest controller that allows a `RequestBody` to be nested like this? Of course I could always turn the JSON into a string on the client's side, and parse it in the rest controller but that doesn't really seem elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the RequestBody parameter as a JsonNode:

```
public <something> myService(@RequestBody JsonNode jsonNode) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a class that looks like :

```java
public class Form {
    private String id;
    private Expression fullexpression;

    // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

where the class Expression has the fields left, operator (String), and right.

Since the type of left and right fields can be String or Expression, I would suggest you to set their type to Map<String,Expression> or JsonNode.. but I didn't test yet.